Running a different function based on compile-time constant parameters
I have this function to fill a buffer with a repeating pattern of N bytes:
void* memsetPattern(void* buf, size_t bufSize, const void* Pattern, size_t PatternSize) {
    if (buf == nullptr || Pattern == nullptr || PatternSize == 0) { return nullptr; }
    if (bufSize == 0) { return buf; } // 0 Bytes to copy
    if (PatternSize == 1) {
        memset(buf, ((uint8_t*)Pattern)[0], bufSize);
        return buf;
    }
    /* otherwise, if PatternSize >= 2 */
}

If the PatternSize is 1 byte, the function will instead run:
memset(buf, ((uint8_t*)Pattern)[0], bufSize)

Since memset() runs slightly faster than my function.
If the user wanted to call:
memsetPattern(buf, bufSize, Pattern, 1)

Would it be possible to directly call:
(Pattern != nullptr && buf != nullptr) ? memset(buf, ((uint8_t*)Pattern)[0], bufSize) : nullptr

Since PatternSize would be known to equal 1 byte at compile-time?
I suppose one way to do it is with macros, but it just feels wrong:
#define memsetPattern_Macro(buf, bufSize, Pattern, PatternSize) \
(PatternSize == 1) ? ( \
    (Pattern != nullptr && buf != nullptr) ? memset(buf, ((uint8_t*)Pattern)[0], bufSize) : nullptr \
) : memsetPattern(buf, bufSize, Pattern, PatternSize)

Looking around, I did find if constexpr, but it gives an error when I try:
if constexpr (PatternSize == 1) {


'PatternSize' is not a constant expression

How should I go about switching the function based on parameters that are known at compile-time? Would I need to change the types of arguments that are passed into the memsetPattern() function?

You are optimizing prematurely.  Those if statements are a few instructions at most and will have an insignificant impact on performance.

I was mostly curious on how it could be done, I am aware that it would only save 10ns at best

In a nutshell, you should be using template function(s) to accomplish this, not concrete functions.

Perhaps this is at the wrong level? Isn't the caller aware that the size is constant 1? Why call a function to set a single byte?

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?  Note that the test for PatternSize >= 2 does not show up in the assembly output, showing that the compiler only generated the code for PatternSize == 1.

Do you have to support both compile-time and runtime sizes? If you do, is it acceptable to rely on the user to use a slightly different form to call the function when the size is known at compile time? (Something like memsetPattern(buf, bufSize, Pattern, PatternSize) for runtime sizes and memsetPattern<PatternSize>(buf, bufSize, Pattern) for compile-time sizes.)

Actually, for trivial things like this, just make the function inline (well, you don't even need to do that explicitly). If optimization is turned on, the compiler should eliminate the unused path anyway.


If the user wanted to call memsetPattern(buf, bufSize, Pattern, 1), would it be possible to directly call (Pattern != nullptr && buf != nullptr) ? memset(buf, ((uint8_t*)Pattern)[0], bufSize) : nullptr since PatternSize would be known to equal 1 byte at compile time?

Yes, and that's exactly what you're doing already.
Any optimizing compiler will already inline functions and then utilize known constants, such as if Pattern is always 1.
For example, if you write the following:
void* foo(void* buf, size_t bufSize, const void* Pattern) {
    return memsetPattern(buf, bufSize, Pattern, 1);
}

... then GCC optimizes this to (https://godbolt.org/z/W16E6ffee):
foo(void*, unsigned long, void const*):
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L17
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L17
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .L22
        sub     rsp, 8
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdx]
        mov     rdx, rsi
        mov     esi, eax
        call    memset
        ...

The only branches prior to an unconditional call to memset are testing whether buf, Pattern, or bufSize are zero/null. The test for PatternSize == 1 and PatternSize == 0 is completely removed.
You've probably been told this before: Don't optimize prematurely. Have some faith in your compiler.
That being said, you could use if constexpr if PatternSize is say, a template parameter:
template <size_t PatternSize>
void* memsetPattern(void* buf, size_t bufSize, const void* Pattern) {
    if constexpr (PatternSize == /* ... */)
    // ...
}

However, you should only do this when you absolutely need a constant expression PatternSize, such as when it's used as the size of an array etc. Otherwise you're just worsening the ergonomics of this function and increasing code size with questionable benefits.
